# Order of objects in List after converting List to Map<Key, List> in Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary

Let's say there is a `List<SexAndAge>` that contains men age from 1 to 100 and woman age from 1 to 100 in ascending order. When I do `list.stream.collect(groupingBy(SexAndAge::getSex))`, It will be `Map<String, List<SexAndAge>>`.

And I am wondering if the order of objects in map.value() will be always the same.
As far as I tested it, it seems like it preserve always the same order.

I know that the key part of map won't keep order as long as I do something else.
But, List keeps added order.

is order of the list in map.value() the same always?
And are there any documentation about this?